# Object.assign javascript

Tags: javascript, объекты

:)
Вот я создаю 3 объекта:

```
let user = { who: "God", age: 13759613215 };
let obj1 = { someKey1: "dsvygsd" };
let obj2 = { someKey2: "sdvtglmha" };
```

Копирую свойства obj1 и obj2 и user.

```
Object.assign( user, obj1, obj2 );
```

Вызываю ключи через alert.

```
for (let key in user) {
    alert(key);
}
```

Ну и всплывающее окно выводит их по порядку: who, age, someKey1, someKey2.

И вот ставлю я значит скобки квадратные тут

```
Object.assign( user, [obj1, obj2] );
```

И теперь цикл

```
for (let key in user) {
        alert(key);
    }
```

Выдает мне: 0, 1, who, age.
Почему там 0 и 1?

Comment: Потому что `[obj1, obj2]` - это массив с индексами 0 и 1.

Comment: То есть закинул в объект массив, и вызов ключей свойств мне выдает индексы массивов? Я не понимаю все равно как это работает, даже если это массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign): первым передаваемым параметром, является целевой объект, куда будут добавляться свойства, все остальные параметры - это объекты, чьи свойства будут добавляться.

В случае

```
Object.assign( user, obj1, obj2 );
```

Происходит передача трех параметров:

- user - целевой объект
- obj1 - первый источник
- obj2 - второй источник

В случае

```
Object.assign( user, [obj1, obj2] );
```

Происходит передача двух параметров:

- user - целевой объект
- [obj1, obj2] - первый источник

Так как источником является массив - в целевой объект добавляются его свойства `0` и `1`, соответствующие каждому элементу массива.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `[obj1, obj2]` - это массив с индексами 0 и 1.

```js
let obj1 = { someKey1: "dsvygsd" };
let obj2 = { someKey2: "sdvtglmha" };

for (let key in [obj1, obj2]) {
  console.log(typeof key, key);
}
```

Comment: Я создал 3 объекта, свойства из двух кидаю в один. Имена объектов стали массивом и свойства не передались, а с помощью цикла вывода ключей мне выдаются индексы массивов, как ета? Почему с помощью for(let key in user) мне выдает и ключи первого объекта и индексы массива из двух других обектов?

Comment: @nx4n Я не понимаю что Вы говорите. Фраза "Имена объектов стали массивом" - бессмысленная. Никакие "имена" массивом не стали. Прочитайте еще раз ответ. Не торопитесь. Подумайте. Не используйте слово "кидать", когда говорите о коде.

Comment: В общем создался массив из имен(переменных) объектов. Почему цикл вообще мне выдает индексы, а затем ключи свойств первого объекта?

Comment: @nx4n Что не работает?

Comment: Я исправил комментарий, извиняюсь.

Comment: @nx4n Потому что индексы являются перечисляемыми свойствами массива.

Comment: Типа 0: "obj1" {someKey1:"dsvygsd"} ? Так сделал Object.assign для user?

Answer (score 1):

Массивы в javascript - это тоже объекты, ключами которых являются числа, т.е. запись `[obj1, obj2]` почти эквивалентна записи `{"0": obj1, "1": obj2}`, и когда вы пытаетесь объединить объект user и массив `[obj1, obj2]`, то фактически вы пытаетесь объединить user и другой объект с ключами "0" и "1"

Comment: Понял, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

function shallowCopy(obj) {
const res = Object.assign({}, obj);
return res
}

const myObj = {
one: 1,
two: 2,
three: 3
};

const myObjCopy = shallowCopy(myObj);

console.log(myObjCopy === myObj); // false

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).